# How to get the sum of divisors in a given range efficiently?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the sum of all divisors of `c` in a give range a, b a <= b.

I've tried to loop from `a` to `b` and sum all divisors of `c`, but this seems inefficient, because the absolute difference between a and b can be 10^9.
Is there a way that reduces the time complexity of this approach?

```
int a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
long long sum = 0;
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++) {
    if (i % c == 0) {
       ans += i;
    }
}
cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: You can try to find the prime factorization of `c` and then derive all possible divisors (in range `[a, b]`) from them. That's significantly more complicated though.

Comment: ... and you need to consider possible duplicates (e. g. 4 will appear multiple times with prime factorisation of 2, 2, 2, if you pair any factors with any other ones).

Comment: @Aconcagua "working" is a subjective adjective if you do not specify the acceptance criterion. Here, OP clearly states their implementation is not performant enough: it then needs correction. This is on-topic. If you're unsure, you can ask it on [meta].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify all the prime numbers that are divisors of c first.  That will leave you with a list of numbers [w,x,y,z…].  Then keep a hash table set of all multiples of integers in this list that are also divisors.

```
int a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
long long sum = 0;

std::vector<int> all_prime_factors = // Get all prime factors of c
std::unordered_set<int> factorSet;
for (int primefactor : all_prime_factors)
{
    int factor = primefactor;
    while (factor <= b)
    {
        if (factor % c == 0)
            factorSet.insert(factor);
        factor += primefactor;
    }
}

for (int x : factorSet)
{
    sum += x;
}

cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Could you have it even quicker? First, add any prime factor to the set, then add any product of two prime factors, then any of 3, then... Sure, that's not trivial - and getting prime factors differs then: while original approach would prefer to avoid dupplicates, this one *requires* duplicates retained...

Comment: Why for a=12, b=18, c=6 it prints 12? No matter how much I try to interpret the question, this result makes no sense to me

Comment: Assuming the fix with `factor += primefactor` this runs in O((b-a) * log(c) / log(log c).  This is much slower than the alternative implementation of O(1).

Answer (score 3):

Note: the question is unclear whether we need to sum divisors (in the description) or divisible integers (in the code sample). The answer sums up divisible items.

This is simple.

- Find `from`, the smallest value such that `from % c == 0 && from >= a`
- Find `to`, the largest value such that `to % c == 0 && to <= b`

.

```
 int n = (to - from) / c + 1;
 return n * (to + from) / 2;
```

Return `to - from + c`. Take care of boundary conditions when `to` could overflow your type and `from` can underflow.

To find `from` do something like:

```
if (c < 0) c *= -1;  // works unless c == MIN_INT
if (a % c == 0)
   from = a;
else if (a >= 0)
   from = (a / c * c) + c
else 
   from = a / c * c;
```

Similarly for `to`, but accounting for the fact that we need to round down, and not up.

Also, need to handle the case of `a > b` separately.

## EDIT

Here is the complete code with no loops, recursion, or containers. It runs in O(1):

```
int a, b, c;
std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
if (!std::cin) {
   std::cout << "input error\n";
   return 0;
}

if (c < 0) c*= -1;
const int from = [a,c] {

   // no rounding needed
   if (a % c == 0) return a;

   // division rounds down to zero
   if (a > 0) return (1 + a / c) * c;

   // division rounds up to zero
   return a / c * c;
}();

const int to = [b,c] {

   // no rounding needed
   if (b % c == 0) return b;

   // division rounds down to zero
   if (b > 0) return (b / c) * c;

   // division rounds up to zero
   return (b / c - 1) * c;
}();

int64_t sum = 0;
if (from <= to)
{
 const int n = (to - from) / c + 1;
 sum = n * (to + from) / 2;
}
std::cout << sum << '\n';
```

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a multiplication lacking? c = 6, a = 5, b = 30 -> from = 6, to = 30 -> to-from+c = 30-6+6 = 30; numbers dividable: 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, sum is 90.

Comment: @Aconcagua fixed